# Nuxt application doesn't send email using nuxt-mail and axios

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm building an app in nuxt that take in input some data and send an email when user click submit button.

this is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" v-model="user_data.name" />
    </form>

    <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" v-model="user_data.surname" />
    </form>

    <form action="">
      <input type="tel" name="" id="" v-model="user_data.phone" />
    </form>

    <form action="">
      <input type="email" name="" id="" v-model="user_data.email" />
    </form>

    <button type="submit" @click="sendMail">submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user_data: {
        name: "",
        surname: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
      },
    };
  },

  methods: {
    sendMail() {
      this.$mail.send({
        from: "cliente",
        subject: "candidatura",
        text: "caio sto testando la mail",
        to: "mymail@gmail.com",
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I've installed nuxt-mail and axios and I've cofigured it

```
 modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    ['nuxt-mail', {
      
      message: {
        to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
      },
      smtp: {
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
      },
    }],
  ],
```

I'm trying to compile the form and submit but i don't receive mail

Comment: And where is message from? Your email/password to account you want to use as smtp.gmail.com? Are you sure you set up everything? You need to enable in Gmail ability to use your account as SMTP. You should get an error. Did you try to get that error and read what is all about?

Comment: @Mises message is from user mail that i recover as $this.email (not as in share code), I receive an error that is 'authentication required' I will try to configure an auth section in nuxt.config file

Comment: Well, as far as I know, setting Gmail SMTP need to contain not only host and port but an email and password of account you want to use. I don't see those settings in your code. And why you not show any code where you actually have an API that will send an email?

Comment: @Mises, I don't have a code with an api... i was trying  to do this just from nuxt without a backend

Comment: anyway I should use aruba, but if I try with an aruba mail return me same error

Comment: Well, `nuxt-mail` module uses `nodemailer` library, and it works in node environment.

Comment: @Mises so what I should do to send mail?

Comment: Things I wrote before.

Comment: @Mises so I should create a node.js backend with api?

Comment: Nuxt has that already read about Nuxt API

Comment: @Mises sorry I'm new of this framework and I don't find tutorial